Some additional conclusions on the Extension Theorem of Sobolev Spaces
Extension theorem says that for a given $\Omega$ bounded domain and $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ there exists $E(u) \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that:

$E(u) = u$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$
$\text{supp}(E(u)) \subset V$, where $\Omega \subset \subset V$.
There exists $C > 0$ such that  $\|u\|_{H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^N)} \leq C \|u\|_{H^{1}(\Omega)}$.

In this post post is discussed one more thing about 2), namely $\text{supp}(|\nabla E(u)|) \subset V$. Now I wonder about one more additional conclusion about item $1)$: Is it true that $|\nabla E(u)| = |\nabla u|$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$? Another question is if the constant $C$ in item $3)$ depends on the set $V$.

If two functions agree a.e. on an open set, then the same is true for their weak derivatives.

Thank you for the answer.

What about the dependence of the constant on $V$? Can we say the constant $C$ just depends on $\Omega?$

The constant depends on $V$. If you make $V$ smaller then the constant increases.

If $V \subset W$, for some open set $W$, can we take the constant $C$ only depending on $W$?
